# Разбиение массива символов на подмассивы по маске

Tags: java, массивы

Есть массив из 70 символов. Нужно разделить его на 4 подмассива по следующему признаку:

> 1223344122334412233441223344122334412233441223344122334412233441223344

где цифра - это номер подмассива.

Не совсем понимаю, как именно добавить в подмассив элемент массива. Читал, что в таких случаях лучше использовать коллекции, но хотелось бы использовать именно массивы.

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
String answers = reader.next();
char[] answersArray = answers.toCharArray();
char[] firstGroup;
char[] secondGroup;
char[] thirdGroup;
char[] fourthGroup;
int i = 0;
while (i < answersArray.length - 1) {
    firstGroup[] = answersArray[i];
    secondGroup[] = answersArray[i + 1];
    secondGroup[] = answersArray[i + 2];
    thirdGroup[] = answersArray[i + 3];
    thirdGroup[] = answersArray[i + 4];
    fourthGroup[] = answersArray[i + 5];
    fourthGroup[] = answersArray[i + 6];
    i += 10;
}
```

Comment: Может, вы приведете примеры своего кода, идеи или что-то еще? Даже такой элементарный код просто так за вас вряд ли станут писать.

Comment: для начала тебе нужно инициализировать массивы. А для этого нужно знать их длину.....а  для этого нужно в начале сделать как минимум еще один цикл и посчитать, сколько раз каждая цифра встречается в массиве с 12233441... ..а только потом делать цикл .... в котором, возможно, проще использовать switch/case или if, чтобы класть значение в нужный массив

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно использовать именно массивы, то можно поступить так:

- Посчитать количество вхождений каждой цифры (`1`...`4`) в строку-маску
- Создать подмассивы так, чтобы их длины совпадала с количеством вхождений соответствующей (первый подмассив - `1` и т.д.) цифры
- Пройтись по всем символам исходного массива (`answersArray`) и разнести их по подмассивам с учетом маски

Код может получиться такой:

```
public static char[][] parse(char[] answersArray, String mask)
{
    final int subArraysCount = 4;
    final char maskShift = '1';
    int[] count = new int[subArraysCount];
    char[] maskChars = mask.toCharArray();
    for (char c : maskChars)
    {
        count[c - maskShift]++;
    }
    char[][] result = new char[subArraysCount][];
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = new char[count[i]];
    }
    int[] indices = new int[result.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < answersArray.length; i++)
    {
        int arraysIndex = maskChars[i] - maskShift;
        int inArrayIndex = indices[arraysIndex];
        result[arraysIndex][inArrayIndex] = answersArray[i];
        indices[arraysIndex]++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

- Все подмассивы объединены в один массив массивов, чтобы было удобнее работать с ними и не плодить лишние переменные
- Количество подмассивов задано константой. Если нужно будет его высчитывать на основании маски, то для этого придётся добавить ещё один цикл по символам маски

Answer (score 0):

Через коллекции можно сделать так:

```
Map<String, List<String>> repository = new HashMap<>();

    String original = "1223344122334412233441223344122334412233441223344122334412233441223344";
    for (char c : original.toCharArray()) {
        String str = String.valueOf(c);
        List<String> symbols = repository.get(str);
        if (symbols == null) {
            symbols = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        symbols.add(str);
        repository.put(str, symbols);
    }

    System.out.println(repository);
```

И тогда не зависимо от самих символов и их количества у Вас будет происходить разбиение на отдельные коллекции. Если есть нужда получить потом из коллекций массивы, то можно воспользоваться подобной инструкцией (предварительно дописав, ибо мой пример вернёт массив только для первой коллекции в map'е):

```
repository.values().iterator().next().toArray(new String[]{});
```

Если же требуется всё это проделать через массивы, то вам на каждую вставку символа придется пересоздавать массив, так как изначальная длинна последовательности символов может быть не известна. Но можете попробовать посчитать количество вхождений каждого символа в строке, и тогда можно будет заранее создать массивы нужной длины.